# Почему у label разная яркость?

Tags: python, kivy

Допустим у меня такой код:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout()
        root.add_widget(Label(text="test"))
        root.add_widget(Label(text="test"))
        return root

MyApp().run()
```

При каждом запуске лейблы всегда то темнее , то светлее и всегда по разному. Почему? и как сделать что бы было всегда одинаково?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему обновлением до последней версии kivi 1.11.0rc2